# Change cc_binary link type without modyfing a target

Tags: bazel

I want to build my `cc_binary` target in a dynamic mode `linkstatic=False`, but without modifying a target definition.
My use case: I want to build static binaries in the CI, but for development purposes I want to use dynamic linking to speedup incremental builds. Probably some flag in `bazel build/test` invocation would be the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`--dynamic_mode`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--dynamic_mode) flag.